# NextJS Redundant Url Params For SEO

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am switching over from React and ExpressJS to NextJS which i know is technically the same thing but NextJS makes it much easy to setup SEO with SSR server side rendering.

In my ReactJS setup I was adding the title and cat of the post to the url mainly for SEO no other reason I am only using the id in the react function.

I was using routes like this.

```
<Route path="/posts/:query/:id/:title" element={<Posts />} />
```

I am not sure how to do this with NextJS as you use dynamic routes via the file name.

```
posts
  [id].js
```

So these urls work.

```
https://example.com/{post-id}
```

But for SEO reasons only I think it makes sense to also add the cat and title in the url structure.

```
https://example.com/{post-id}/{cat}/{title}
```

With NextJS how can add these to the url structure and still load the [id].js file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turn out its pretty simple.

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

three dots works

```
[...slug].js
```